# While Installing Solace JMS extension on Siddhi, facing Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.jms; version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, siddhi, solace

Siddhi IO JMS extension receives and publishes events via JMS after providing the message broker client jar files and its dependencies in its bundle directories.
Check https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/streaming-integrator/samples/ReceiveJMSInJsonFormat/ to see the official documentation explaining how to connect with Apache MQ.

Similar to the above doc example of ActiveMQ, we are trying to implement connection with Solace. After providing the sol-jms.jar and its dependencies (check images below) in Siddhi’s respective bundle directories, we face error coming from module **com.solacesystems.sol-jms** stating **Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.jms; version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"**
We tried providing javax.jms jars of version 2.0.1 and 2.0 but could not find any version between 1.1.0 and < 2.0.0.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
I have added the 5 dependencies jars listed on https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.solacesystems/sol-jms/10.12.0
After adding all the dependencies present in sol-jms-10.12.0/lib in a fresh project directory, I am still facing the same issue.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Edited question showing another trial of pushing all the dependency jars present in solace-jms-10.12.0/lib

Answer (score 1):

If I download the Solace JMS library from solace.com/downloads it seems to come with these jars. I don't see all of these in your image. Are you including a subset of what is begin downloaded or where are you getting your solace jars from?

[image]

Comment: further to what @Mrc0113 said above... you require the Solace JMS provider JARs to be on your classpath to make this work. On the page you link, it shows how to set up for ActiveMQ JMS provider by getting its JARs. The process would be similar but for Solace JARs.

The JARs can be downloaded on the Solace website: https://solace.com/downloads/ or from Maven central repo